# Android Sudio, cant get a program working with api and listview

Tags: java, android, json, api

i have this problem that i cant pull back api info to a program. I checked some tutorials but nothing helped. Mabey someone knows what could be the problem or could provide some usefull links to fix the issue. i am doing a simple currency exchange display app to upgrade my skills and learn more of android studio. Thank you in advance!

Main activity

```
package com.example.currencyapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mCurrencies;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCurrencies = findViewById(R.id.currencies);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();

            }
        });

    }
    private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("rates");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                               JSONObject rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                               String rates = rate.getString("rates");

                               mCurrencies.(rates);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);

    }
}
```

xml activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/currencies"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="597dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="169dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="141dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="141dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:text="parse" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `mCurrencies.(rates);` is not a valid java statement

Comment: Yeah i saw it getting a error on it but it only says "rename reference". Maby you know what could help to solve this issue? because i have list view where i want to display the information from the api and i cant figure it out how to :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice, the api response "rates" is not a JSONArray it is a JSONObject.

```
{
   "rates":{
      "CAD":1.5621,
      "HKD":9.533,
      "ISK":156.1,
      "PHP":59.058,
      ...
     }
}
```

why is `mCurrencies` type ListView ?. did you mean `List<String>`

I created a function that will help you get the response as List

```
List<String> parser(JSONObject response) {
        HashMap<String, String> currencies = new HashMap<>();
        JSONObject exchangeRates = response.optJSONObject("rates");
        Iterator<String> keys = exchangeRates.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            String value = exchangeRates.optString(key);
            currencies.put(key, value);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(currencies.values());
    }
```

Now in your code use it like this

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    mCurrencies = parser(response)
}
```

Don't use try-catch, instead, use optString it's much safer.

Comment: I am very thankful for your response and I am very happy to be in this community. Your answer provided me a lot of guidance and by running it line by line and im pretty sure what it does. unfortunately, as a complate begginer i am having major issues with including your code functionalities into my application. It seams i have tried putting it in every possible place of the code, but something still goes wrong :(. May I ask you to provide some more help or explanation? thank you for your time, it means a lot!

Comment: @Mintasis00 This is the closest I could get based on your question. If you are still facing the issue, please share the GitHub project, will check what's the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, here is my git hub url for the code ( https://github.com/mintautasi/currencyapperoli ), if you will spare your time to check it it would be amazing!